# gui with multiple interfaces?

Tags: jquery-ui, user-interface

I am trying to create a GUI using jquery and html to allow users to enter information into a system.  The problem is, I don't know how to create a GUI that will show different interfaces for each step.

For example, I want to have users enter in their personal information in step 1.  When they click next, they can choose a photo from a set of photos that appear, and so on.

I suppose I can name different html divs and make them show and hide at certain times as desired.  But is there a cleaner technique for doing something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use one of the JQuery Form Wizard extensions.

For example:

http://thecodemine.org